# Terminate whole pipeline across machines on terminating error

Tags: powershell, error-handling, powershell-4.0

I am trying to automate a task that is performed by manually calling the **slave** script, that I don't want to modify more than necessary and need to leave the ability to use it manually.

So far I managed to create a calling script that does what we used to do manually, but I can't find an elegant way to end the pipeline upon first terminating error.

The idea is that if a terminating error is encountered anywhere in either the master or the slave, the whole pipeline terminates with an error status.

This is the furthest I got:

#### PipelineMaster.ps1

```
$groups = (@('server1', 'server2', 'server3'), @('server4'))
trap { 
    'trap at master';
    if ($_.FullyQualifiedErrorId -ne 1) { Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_ }
    throw 1 
}

ForEach ($group in $groups) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $group[0] -ArgumentList $group -ScriptBlock {
        param([Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)][String[]]$group)
        trap { 
            'trap at invocation';
            if ($_.FullyQualifiedErrorId -ne 1) { Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_ }
            throw 1 
        }
        
        # preparation per group
        .\PipelineSlave.ps1 -group $group
    } 
}
```

#### PipelineSlave.ps1:

```
param([string[]]$group)
trap { 
    'trap at slave';
    if ($_.FullyQualifiedErrorId -ne 1) { Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_ }
    throw 1 
}

ForEach ($h in $group) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $h -ScriptBlock {
        trap { 
            'trap at node';
            if ($_.FullyQualifiedErrorId -ne 1) { Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_ }
            throw 1
        }
        " ## $(hostname)"
        "minor err"; New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path c:\
        'major err'; New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path c:\temp -ErrorAction Stop
        " ## Done on $(hostname)"
    }
}
```

This utilises `trap` at every scope level.

I experimented with $? after each scope ended, but that is triggered upon non-terminating errors as well and I found no way to differentiate.

Another option was to simply wrap everything in `try` and `throw 1` upon getting there. As a **side question**: why does `try{...} catch {throw}` work in a different way from `try{...} catch {throw 1}`? The former only terminates the context, the latter the whole pipeline and I could not find any article that explained it.

Finally, I also experimented with this (simplified here):

```
ForEach ($group in $groups) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $group[0] -ArgumentList $group -ScriptBlock {
        ForEach ($h in $group) {
            Invoke-Command ComputerName $h -ScriptBlock {
                New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path C:\
                New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path C:\temp
                if (!$?) { return 'ERROR' }
                "Done on $(hostname)"
            } | % {if ('ERROR' -eq $_) {return 'ERROR'} else {$_}}
        }
    } | % {if ('ERROR' -eq $_) {return 'ERROR'} else {$_}}
}
```

This did what I wanted (mostly), but instead of relying on native PS differentiation between terminating and non-terminating errors, I need to make sure the error is non-terminating and then check result of each command I want to terminate on.

I realise I could also do the above but do `throw 1` instead of `return 'ERROR'`, but that is much like the first approach and more tedious.

Note: Commands are not necessarily New-Item, but they are a reliable way to trigger both terminating and non-terminating errors in PS.

Comment: You want terminating errors to ... terminate? That's what they do. Just remove the trap's. Or clarify your problem, please.

Comment: @marsze Yes... If I remove the traps, they terminate the environment only, not the whole pipeline, so in case of terminating error on 'server2', the execution would be:
"run on server1: OK"
"run on server2: ERROR, aborted"
"run on server4..."
It's cool that it skips 'server3', but still continues to 'server4' - that's my problem.